# $BROADCASTing from service to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little concern here

This comes from a service named `BetSlipFactory`

```
  removeSlip: function(slip) {

    return betSlipSelectionRequest('/betSlip/removeSelection', {
      game: slip.game,
      pair: slip.pair,
      line: slip.line
    });
  }
```

Then I have this function in the controller for that service

```
$scope.removeSlip = function(slip) {

  $rootScope.$broadcast('betSlip:removeLines', slip);
  BetSlipFactory.removeSlip(slip)

}
```

Next I have a controller in a different scope named `LinesCtrl` and I have this function here which calls a couple functions from the service `BetSlipFactory` which is like a kind of toggle function

```
$rootScope.$on('betSlip:removeLines', function(event, slip) {
  if (slip) {
    BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);
  };
});

$scope.addLineToBetSlip = function(line, row, type) {
  var spreadSelected = (row.spreadSelected && type === 'spread'),
    totalSelected = (row.totalSelected && type === 'total'),
    moneyLineSelected = (row.moneyLineSelected && type === 'moneyline');
  if (spreadSelected || totalSelected || moneyLineSelected) {

    BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);

  }else {

    BetSlipFactory.add(line, row, type);

  }
};
```

And then the HTML:

```
     <button ng-click="removeSlip(slip)"></button>
```

And:

```
     <td ng-class="!row.moneyLineSelected ? 'lines-hover' : 'line-selected'">
        <a ng-click="addLineToBetSlip(line, row, 'moneyline')">
           <span ng-hide="row.noMoneyLine">{{:: row.moneyLine}}</span>
        </a>
     </td>
```

What I need: combine the scopes, when the function `$scope.removeSlip(slip)` is call, also I need to call `$scope.addLineToBetSlip(line, row, type)` and then that function should call `BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);` as it is within that `if` statement.

When I call $scope.removeSlip(slip) I need to kill `slip` parameter, within the scope of `BetSlipFactory` everything works great.

[I recorded a video for you to see what I am talking about](https://youtu.be/urL0cmRHZrI), let me explain the video a little bit.

In the first 2 tries you might see that I am able to select and deselect and everything works great, but in the 3rd and 4th try, you see that I select a line, and then I go a call and `removeSlip(slip)` when I play the X on the right, and in order to deselect the line on the left I have to do it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with $broadcast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926552/issue-with-broadcast)

Comment: so basically what you're saying is that when closing the bet with the X, you need to clear the selection on the money line button to the left?

Comment: @floribon is different, nobody answer to my other question this is a better explained question. Yisus. first wait for someone to answer.

Comment: @Ronnie something like that sir.

Comment: does clicking the money line button toggle the bet being added/removed?

Comment: what about using `$emit` instead of `$broadcast`? does that change anything?

Comment: @Ronnie yes, if you make that process from the left panel works properly, you click on the money line and the line is added to the right panel, if you click again on the same line, that line is removed from the right line panel and yellow color changes to white again, but if you try to remove the line by clicking in the X button in the panel right, the line is removed but the yellow color is still there, so there is something wrong here, that's what I need to do it with a broadcast

Comment: ok, so the css class on the button is set by `row.moneyLineSelected`. Are you sure that value is updating correctly?

Comment: yes, @Ronnie, see the ```ng-class``` in the HTML,, that's why when you select and deselect the lines in the panel right, the class is been applied and removed, which means that the value is updating correctly.

Comment: I'm going to have to recreate something to test this unless you can provide the code. This seems it should be easier than the way you're doing it; i.e. `when the function $scope.removeSlip(slip) is call, also I need to call $scope.addLineToBetSlip(line, row, type)` you add and then remove? That doesn't make sense

Comment: are the two panels using the same controller? If not, why?

Comment: @Ronnie I said: ```$scope.addLineToBetSlip(line, row, type)``` and then that function should call ```BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);``` as you can see I need to call the first function which contains ```BetSlipFactory.remove(line, row, type);```, I don't to call ``BetSlipFactory.add(line, row, type);```, only the one with the remove method

Comment: @Ronnie are completely different controllers, one is for betslip and other for lines, that's the way we have to handle it.

Comment: alright i am working on a fiddle..where do the available bets come from?

Comment: @Ronnie all that info comes from a DB, I will be posting the full code in a Plunkr, just give me 2 minutes.

Comment: @Ronnie see the Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/gZnkw4hHAEonZy1nUZSE?p=catalogue, it is not functional, but there you can check the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I started a fiddle showing this process dumbed way down compared to the plnkr you started after. Here I am using two separate controllers and a service (factory) to manage the data. This can be done without using `$rootScope` or `$broadcast`. Hopefully you can take what I have done here and integrate it into all that code you posted on plnkr. Below you can see it is quite a simple process

<kbd>[the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8gk5yjp/1/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div id="colLeft" ng-controller="LeftController">
        <div ng-repeat="bet in possibleBets">
            <button ng-class="!bet.moneyLineSelected ? 'lines-hover' : 'line-selected'" ng-click="addLineToBetSlip(bet)">{{bet.name}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="colRight" ng-controller="RightController">
        Your Bets:<br>
        <div ng-repeat="bet in bets">
            Active bet: {{bet.name}} - <button ng-click="removeLineFromBetSlip(bet)">&times;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lines-hover {

}

.line-selected {
    background:yellow;
}

#colLeft {
    width:65%;
    background:#f00;
    float:left;
}

#colRight {
    width:35%;
    background:gray;
    float:left;
}
```

and finally the JS

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

app.controller('LeftController', function($scope, BetSlipFactory)
{
    // this data is the data from your DB
    $scope.possibleBets = [
        {name:'Bet 1',moneyLineSelected:false},
        {name:'Bet 2',moneyLineSelected:false},
        {name:'Bet 3',moneyLineSelected:false}
    ];

    // now that I think about it, addLineToBetSlip is not a good name
    // since it actually toggles the bet
    $scope.addLineToBetSlip = function(bet)
    {
        bet.moneyLineSelected = !bet.moneyLineSelected; // toggle the moneyLineSelected boolean
        (bet.moneyLineSelected) ? BetSlipFactory.add(bet) : BetSlipFactory.remove(bet); // add or remove the bet
    };
});

app.controller('RightController', function($scope, BetSlipFactory)
{
    $scope.bets = BetSlipFactory.getAllBets(); // link to all the active bets

    // remove the bet from the factory
    $scope.removeLineFromBetSlip = function(bet)
    {
        bet.moneyLineSelected = false;
        BetSlipFactory.remove(bet);
    };
});

app.service('BetSlipFactory', function()
{
    //a place to keep active bets
    var theBets = [];
    return {
        add: function(bet)
        {
            // actually add the bet to this local array
            theBets.push(bet);
        },
        remove: function(bet)
        {
            // you should do error checking of the index before removing it
            var index = theBets.indexOf(bet);
            theBets.splice(index,1);
        },
        getAllBets: function()
        {
            //simply return all active bets
            return theBets;
        }
    }
});

function log(msg)
{
    console.log(msg);
}
```